# check for recieving info from all sockets connected to a server socket java

Tags: java, sockets, cl

in my game i need to check for recieving data from any of the sockets (clients) connected. the clients that are connected are saved to an array. is there a way to check for recieving from any of the clients connected? i have tried a for loop for all of the clients/sockets connected and checked for that but it doesnt seem to work. heres my for loop

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            for (Socket client : Server.clients) {
                Server.in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("recieving information...");
                String input = Client.in.readUTF();

                Server.out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                Server.out.writeUTF("connected");
                send(input);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

but i think it is only checking for one client at a time. also it doesnt help that i could be sending data wrong (or other error) so its hard to find the problem. thanks.

Comment: Could you not simply check that `Server.in.available() > 0` before performing a read? This would prevent any blocking issues that you are facing

Answer (score 1):

`client.in.readUTF()` is going to block your code until that specific socket has data to read, so your loop is going to get stuck. For this you'll want to spawn a new `Thread` object each time you receive a connection on your `ServerSocket`. Something like this:

```
//receive new socket
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         //while loop that waits for input on the socket
    }
}).start();
```

It might be better to have a collection of `Thread`s and actually name them instead of leaving them anonymous like I did here so that you can actually stop them if a socket connection ends.

EDIT: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fW19vmWx) with sample code

Comment: i already use different threads for all of them. do i need a separate thread for every client connected?

Comment: i think i might also not be initiating the new thready the right way. i have my new thread called like

        ServerThread serverin = new ServerThread(10);
        Thread t = new Thread(serverin);
        t.start();
and my class like

    public ServerThread(int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public void run() {
     while (true) {
     }
    }

Comment: It's best to put each client on a separate thread, yes. I'm not totally sure what the int for `ServerThread` does but if you want to subclass `Thread` it might be best to pass in `Socket`s as you receive them from the `ServerSocket`, then the `ServerThread` can listen to that socket and handle all incoming information, as well as being able to send information over its individual `Socket`.

Comment: the client num is for when i add my clients to a Socket[]. then when i need to send some data to all of the sockets i can do a for loop for all of the clients. is there a better way to send data to all connected?

Comment: Usually when you get a Concurrent Modification Exception on a HashMap, it's because you're modifying its key set while you're iterating over it. The best way to get around this is to make a copy of its keys, then use those in the loop. That way, you're free to change the HashMap any way you want.

Comment: In terms of sending a message over each Socket, keeping them in an array and iterating through it, giving each ServerThread the message to send is a totally fine way to do it. As long as it's working I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: im confused on how i would accomplish what you said. so you want me to change the whole rendering method? where do you want me to change the code?

Comment: I'll come up with some basic sample code and send it to you.